# Missing references that don't exist in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, using, dependency-management

I separated out my models from my main ASP.net MVC3 app into a class library which is apart of the same solution as my project and is referenced into my project.

How ever the models in this class library (I copied the models folder over to the class library) are saying things like `system.web.MVC` or `.Security` or even `System.Component.DataAnnotations` do not exist.

So I assumed I could right click on references and click "Add reference" and find those .net libraries but alas they do not exist.

So how do I include them in? So I can use Data annotations, Security and (apparently) MVC?

Comment: You have to include the DLL's that contain those references in your project.  If they are system DLL's, you have to be running on the correct OS and .NET Framework versions.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, I just stated that clicking "add refrences" in my class library project and searching for the missing DLL's doesn't work as they don't exist in the .net or COM section. They are automatically added in the ASP.net project, but not my class library. Also Im using VS2010 on windows 7 with ASP.net MVC3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have ASP.NET MVC framework installed. If you have them installed, they should show up in your GAC (Global Assembly Cache) which your "reference explorer" pulls its dlls from. You can access the gac via C:\Windows\Assembly.

Comment: I have it installed, I am using it from VS2010 and I have used the Web installed from web matrix to install ASP.net MVC. Theres no way, I know of, that I could create and "run" a MVC project with out installed.

Comment: I have ASP.net MVC3 installed, according to the web installer but dont see DLL's like Web.security or web.MVC

Comment: When you install ASP.NET MVC3, those assemblies should have been loaded into the GAC (C:\Windows\Assembly). Please verify they are in there. If they are not in the GAC, that means something went wrong during installation and you should try uninstalling and reinstalling the MVC.

Comment: Is there a sub folder in C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC that they should be in? if it wasn't installed, which it is according the web installer, how would I be able to create a new MVC3 project in VS (2010)?

Comment: C:\Windows\Assembly is the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). If it is not in that folder, than something went wrong during your installation. I would recommend uninstalling MVC, download the MSI file, and use that to install MVC the 2nd time around.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on MVC3 project and we have created our project architecture to maintain our classes something like this:

1. Model classes are in their default place in MVC project.
2. We have added the new project Entity which contains the property that matches the database field (column) names.
3. Separate project for (Data Access later) DAL and (Business Access Layer) BAL.

Now how everything works:

Model classes contains the properties that maps the properties in Entity project and also some extra properties which we need during our development as helper properties for e.g. SubmissionType property   to check what type of Submission we have made with the same post method like Save, Update or Delete.

Entity project will contains only the properties which maps the column names in database and BAL will interact with Entity project classes to get or assign the values which needs database operation.

And classes in Entity project will get or assign the values to/from the Model classes. This is all because  our main project can have reference of Entity and BAL projects but not vice versa.

Ok now the question is how these mappings will done? I mean assigning values from Model to Entity classes and vice versa. 
For that we need to add a dll in our project **"Omu.ValueInjecter"**. which you can download from [here](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com). Just need to add it in our application and it will take care of mapping things in just a single line like this:

```
      EmployeeEntities entity = new EmployeeEntities();
      entity.InjectFrom(model);
```

Here I am assigning the value from model to entity which I got from post method. Now This entity object will be passed to BAL and from BAL to DAL.
By implementing this solution you even don't need to move your Model from outside of your project which is a painful effort I guess.

Hope this solution will help you