# So now MVC is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, class-library

I recently asked a question about ripping models out of the core ASP.net MVC 3 application and putting them into a class library. [See question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306289/missing-references-that-dont-exist-in-mvc3).

Which was then answered by stating I have to re-install MVC.

well after spending all morning doing that, I got everything to work, accept for one thing: `System.Web.MVC` which is needed for `[Compare]` before the reinstall, things like `web.secutiry`, `system.componentmodel.dataannotation` were not working but they are now.

The only thing not working is `Web.MVC` is this going to be yet another reinstall?

Comment: That is not appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you verify System.Web.Mvc.dll Path?
_C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies_ or 
_C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\_

Comment: Yes they exist in both places (thank god) but in the class library its all like - I cannot find you. Should I search for it when adding it as a references and add it that way?

Comment: Could you post some screens showing what you have referenced? Also I am going to assume you have restarted your computer right?